# Pricing of Azure Cloud services (or how is usage calculated)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

So, I'm looking making a cloud service using the Azure platform ([here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/cloud-services/)), looked at the pricing and saw it was calculated per hour (or per minutes according to the banner). So I was wondering, in the case of what I want to do, the service will be doing stuff every (for example) 15 minutes, then will sleep for the rest of the duration. Does that mean I'm only gonna be charged for a couple minutes every hour, or will still count the thread sleep as being active, thus counting in the usage? If it's the latter, is there another way to avoid this (part of the service framework maybe?), short of shutting down the service of course?

Comment: For a cloud service, you pay for it to be there, and how much you use it doesn't matter. The only way not to pay is to deallocate it.

Comment: Every service in Azure has its own pricing model. Some are consumption-base. Some let you stop/start. Others are billed until destroyed. You can see all of this in the documentation.

Comment: fyi This has been fully covered (cloud service billing and virtual machine billing) in other answers, including the one I marked as duplicate of.

Answer (score -1):

There are ways on azure to be billed dynamically.  For example,  If you create a function then it will only be provisioned when it is called and you will only be billed for that time.if you use a vm image or website then you will be billed for the whole time it is running even if it is not in use.
Here is a link to the azure functions billing page that describes the details:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/?cdn=disable

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm really new to Azure, so I don't know much about it. Is there a way to (as you say) create a function, then ask Azure to call that function every 15 minutes for example? How is that setup in Azure and in Visual Studio?

Comment: I believe that you would have to call it on a schedule with REST

Comment: By the way there are lots of free azure trainings available through Microsoft

Comment: @FrancisLord Please ask a new question about Azure Functions, rather than trying to start a discussion in comments. Also - as Mike said - plenty of free training / documentation. I suggest starting there, then asking specific programming questions. Your general questions should be answered already in existing documentation.

Comment: Your original question asked about how cloud services are billed. And made no mention of Azure Functions (which is a completely different service).